# Q on filestream and streamreader unicode

Tags: c#

HI all of u,, I have big problem until now no body helped me.
firstly I want to open XXX.vmg (this extension come from Nokia PC Suite) file and read it then write it in richtextbox. I wrote the code there is no error and also there is no reault in the richtextbox

here is my code

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("c:\\XXX.vmg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileW);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
        string s1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] words = s1.Split(' ');
        for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++)

                   richTextBox1.Text +=Envirment.NewLine +  words[i]; 




        `enter code here`


the output at richtextbox just blank line
```

Comment: This assumes .vmg files contain readable Unicode text. Do they? Open a .vmg file in a text editor and post the first few lines.

Comment: 6706:PIN for voucher of  MRP 1 from retailer 86340118 is 48025526503801, Trasaction ID is E100515.2321.20013 and serial number is 88504355691.


those are all lines in XXX.vmg

Comment: According to http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/vmg, VMGs are null-separated. This is not readable text. Can you upload the actual file to a file transfer site like http://www.jetbytes.com/?

Comment: ok, i will upload it 

thank u so much

Comment: http://files3.jetbytes.com/9a61056f9dff070c6739b809a0c9f993

here is the link, it is in VS 2008

Comment: I am waiting for u and this is my mail
habbo95@hotmail.com

Comment: Thanks, but I only needed the .vmg file, not the entire project.

Comment: ok, u will find the .vmg inside the projct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did a bit of Googling for VMG files, and you have a few problems:

1. VMGs contain little-endian Unicode with no byte-order marks. This means standard text methods like `ReadToEnd` or `ReadAllText` won't work unless you specify an encoding.
2. Once you've got the encoding, VMGs include a bunch of SMS headers like VMSG, VCARD, and STATUS blocks. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so you will have to decide what to do with these blocks.

However, you can read the file as text with:

```
string folderPath = @"C:\path\to\your\VMG\folder";
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(folderPath, @"filename.vmg"), Encoding.Unicode))
{
    string s;
    while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // s is a readable SMS block, what do you want to do with it?
    }
}
```

Comment: @hab - Remember to check the Tick next to the answer to accept it.